# Help moving Joomla 1.5 to a new Dir

Tags: apache-2.2, joomla, migration

I have a joomla install that were going to take "live". It currently is in www.markonsolutions.com/joomla

but I would like to move it to either just the root dir or to something like www.markonsolutions.com/m/ (to keep things organized in the direcotry and have a index.html redirect to the m dir

I edited the the configuration.php in the root of the joomla folder to reflect www.markonsolutions.com/m then I renamed the direcotry to M and i can see the text of the front page but it wont load any pictures and all the links link back to /joomla dir

any ideas on what to try next

thanks

Rob

Comment: Noticed the new bounty. Is there something in particular that you're looking for in terms of additional ideas or details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have something that already works perfectly as long as it can access stuff via http://markonsolutions.com/joomla/, so let's just leave that part alone and make it work via http://markonsolutions.com/ too.

First, we'll set your DocumentRoot to the /joomla directory, and then we'll configure an Alias on markonsolutions.com/joomla so that *both* work.  That works around your broken link issue, so you don't have to figure out how to reconfigure Joomla for a new path when it's already working.

In other words, in your httpd.conf, you could set:

```
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs/joomla
```

...and...

```
Alias /joomla /usr/local/apache/htdocs/joomla
```

Standard caveats:

1. I don't know where your Joomla directory actually lives, so you may need to amend the path to fit the details of your environment.
2. Be sure to find the existing DocumentRoot line and change it instead of creating a duplicate entry.
3. If you already have an Alias set on /joomla and it's pointing to the right place, just change the DocumentRoot and leave the Alias alone.  Otherwise, add a new Alias.

Answer (score 2):

I think your paths are hardcoded in template file templates/markon7810/index.php

In "view source" I see all css classes are named "art-". Few Google queries, and in results can bee seen from where "art-" comes from. It is programmatically generated template (Artisteer - joomla template generator).

So, if you do not have images after moving to "/m/", it can be becouse Arister hardcoded **css paths**. All of images in css looks fine (relative paths).

1. If Aristeer asked you to type a path to Joomla!, than save your Arister project, and generate another template based on "markon7810", but this time change Joomla path from /joomla/ to /m/.
2. Check your .htaccess also, if you
   find "/joomla/" path in it, change
   it to "/m/".
3. Do not forget you have three .htaccess files:

   > ```
   > /.htaccess
   > /m/.htaccess
   > /joomla/.htacces
   > ```
4. Make a backup (Joomla and Aristeer files) before making any changes above.

> "and all the links link back to /joomla dir"

If you used "External Link"-s as a menuitems, you must change URL paths now. You should use "Article > Article Layout" for internal links in menus. And, if you need same link in another menu, then use "Alias" menuitem.

---

Btw, you are using "PHP rewrite", not "Apache rewrite" in Joomla!. If you can change that to "Use Apache mod_rewrite", you will avoid "index.php" part of URL.

[image]

Comment: Could be usefull to add a rewrite/redirect from the old to the new location for the images as well.

Comment: Yes, as a temporary solution rewrite/redirect of /joomla/images/ and /joomla/templates/markon7810/ could be very useful, because in posts and custom HTML modules there still may be images and paths witch begins with or includes old "/joomla/" directory. Then we have almost error free new Joomla! and we can browse posts and modules, trying to locate paths beginning with old "/joomla/" part. 

But, after migration it is maybe better to remove that rewrite/redirection. It is bad, or might be risky for SEO (same file on two URLs, too much unnecessary redirects, paths are not in robots.txt, etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure if its apache or not. Its hosted via godaddy

Comment: Yes, it is Apache http://www.markonsolutions.com/asdfasdf/